# Duplicate selected words with sed and replace it

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace

I have to modify a document containing xml data; one modification I couldn't set up with `sed`.

I have to modify the following expressions from:

```
<Bild href_fmt="Bilder/Bildschirmfoto%202012-06_fmt.jpeg" 
href="file:///user/folder/Desktop/Bildschirmfoto%202012-06-18%20um%2013.17.45.png"></Bild>
```

to:

```
<a href="http://test.server.at/media/somefolder/Bildschirmfoto%202012-06_fmt.jpeg" 
target="_blank"><img src="http://test.server.at/media/somefolder/Bildschirmfoto%202012-06_fmt.jpeg" 
alt="" width="350" height="" /></a>
```

My problem: I couldn't duplicate the `Bildschirmfoto%202012-06_fmt.jpeg` to generate the correct new entry. The HTML tag is somewhere in the line, therefore I can't duplicate the whole line...

How can I do this with `sed` or other Linux commands?

Comment: It would be nice if you could take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's@.*href_fmt="[^/]*/\([^"]*\)".*@<a href="http://test.server.at/media/somefolder/\1target="_blank"><img src="http://test.server.at/media/somefolder/\1" alt="" width="350" height="" /></a>@'
```

We need to extract image name which is inside `href_fmt="Bilder/Bildschirmfoto%202012-06_fmt.jpeg"` . therefore first of all we'll write pattern for this :

```
.*href_fmt="[^/]*/\([^"]*\)".*
```

where `.*` matches anything before `href_fmt="` 
`href_fmt="` matches `href_fmt="` =)
`[^/]*/` matches dir name `Bilder/`
`\([^"]*\)` matches our image name.  `\(\)` is used to make group and use it as `\1` in the future
`".*` matches the rest of the line
and now we will replace everything in the line accordinog to next expression:

```
<a href="http://test.server.at/media/somefolder/\1target="_blank"><img src="http://test.server.at/media/somefolder/\1" alt="" width="350" height="" /></a>
```

where `\1` equals to image name as mentioned above.

Hope now it is clear how does it work.

Comment: This looks like a working solution.  Could you expand your answer to showcase it a bit more clearly?

Comment: Added some explanation.